# subsetting a list of data frames using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

My question is why does the last statement "a <- ..." work to give me a subset of that data frame within the list, but when I try to automate the process with a for loop through all data frames in the list I am met with all kinds of warnings and not the answer I am looking for??

```
time <- c(1:20)
temp <- c(2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6)
data <- data.frame(time,temp)

tmp <- c(1,diff(data[[2]]))
tmp2 <- tmp < 0
tmp3 <- cumsum(tmp2)
data1 <- split(data, tmp3)

#this does not work.  I want to automate the successful process below through all data frames in the list "data1"
for(i in 1:length(data1)){
   finale[i] <- subset(data1[[i]], data1[[i]][,2] > 3)
}

#this works to give me a part of what I want
a <- subset(data1[[1]], data1[[1]][,2] >3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you may want to try with `lapply`

```
lapply(data1, function(x) subset(x, x[,2]>3))
```

Same result using a `for` loop

```
finale <- vector("list", length(data1))
for(i in 1:length(data1)){
  finale[[i]] <- subset(data1[[i]], data1[[i]][,2] > 3)
}
```

It works because I preallocate a type and a length for `finale`, it didn't work for you, because you did not declare what `finale` should be.

Comment: Can it be done with a for loop?  My real data is more complex and my condition is more complex than ">3", it is based on a min value within each data frame in the list.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Jilber!  I knew that was the problem, but just didn't know how to specify what finale should be to start.  It seems so simple now, not sure I would have got it though.  THANKS!

Comment: @user1667477 if this helps you, then you can upvote it and if it answers your question, you can mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save a data.frame (2D object) in a vector (1D objetc). Just define `finale` as list and the code will work:

```
time <- c(1:20)
temp <- c(2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6)
data <- data.frame(time,temp)

tmp <- c(1,diff(data[[2]]))
tmp2 <- tmp < 0
tmp3 <- cumsum(tmp2)
data1 <- split(data, tmp3)

#this does not work.  I want to automate the successful process below through all data frames in the list "data1"
finale <- vector(mode='list')
for(i in 1:length(data1)){
   finale[[i]] <- subset(data1[[i]], data1[[i]][,2] > 3) # Use [[i]] instead of [i]
}
```

To save all in 1 data.frame:

```
finale <- do.call(rbind, finale)
```

Comment: How this answer is different to mine?

Comment: You are asking why I posted an answer equal to yours? Simple: When I started to write it, there were no answers here.